# Style SOS point feature via CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors, openlayers

I receive point features via sensorobjectservice (SOS). Their style is not defined in any style.css yet.
If I hover over the feature and inspect one feature element in Firebug it shows up as a  tag with an id like "OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_112". I can change the filling color inline in Firebug but if I define a style in a css file for that id it does not react. The color does not change.

```
#OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_112{
    fill: olive !important;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because, in CSS, dots (.) represents classes. So, when you put #OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_112, the CSS will look for an element with ID #OpenLayers and the classes .Geometry and .Point_112.

Something like this:

```
<element id="OpenLayers" class="Geometry Point_112"></element>
```

to fix this, you need to use a escape character (\) in your CSS:

```css
#OpenLayers\.Geometry\.Point_112{
  display:block;
  background-color: olive;
}
```

```html
<div id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_112">hey</div>
```

more details: [backslash (\) escaping](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)